# Nuxt SSR - Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

Going through the gauntlet of deploying a Nuxt SSR app to firebase hosting. I've been following this [fantastic tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_aTvdnqY3ek). Due to Firebase's limitations with es6-es7, I'm converting my "imports" to "require" and "module.exports". For some reason, when I run firebase deploy --only functions, the deploy fails with the following error:

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bendepew/Developer/aw/pit-road-reporter/prr-nuxtjs/functions/index.js:12:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
```

When I check the error locations, I see that the code that I had manually changed to ES5 syntax has been auto-reverted to ES7 syntax. My first thought was that this could be an eslint issue, but I'm note sure.

**PACKAGE.JSON Scripts**

```
 "scripts": {
        "lint": "eslint",
        "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
        "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
      },
```

**.ESLINT.JS**

```
 module.exports = {
      root: true,
      env: {
        es6: true,
        node: true,
      },
      extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "google",
      ],
      rules: {
        quotes: ["error", "double"],
      },
    };
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue while trying to deploy Nuxt SSR to Firebase Hosting via a Cloud Function?

Comment: It is indeed running in Node 10 as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: @kissu - sorry, not sure what you're asking. I'm using Node14. From what I can see, anything above Node 8 should be ok, right? And I'm on the blaze plan.

Comment: It's annoying that Firebase is stuck with Node 10...